OBJECT_ID fails to find existing temp table
I'm using temp tables to stage data before inserting into production. As a couple of things use them, before anything else I do a:
IF OBJECT_ID(N'##Projects_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
TRUNCATE TABLE ##Projects_TEMP 
ELSE 
SELECT * INTO ##Projects_TEMP FROM Projects WHERE 1=0

The idea is to clear the table if it's there, and make the table if it's not. I believe that T-SQL should do that?
However:
select OBJECT_ID(N'##Projects_TEMP')

always returns NULL. This is surprising, because the table does exist in that connection (I did so manually in SSMS to be sure), and:
select * from ##Projects_TEMP

Works fine. What am I missing here?

Object identifiers are database scoped, and temporary objects live in tempdb. Unless the code you’re running is also in that database context, of course it can’t find it. You need to prefix the object with the correct database.
select OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##Projects_TEMP')


Unless the code you’re running is also in that database context - I am running it manually in a SSMS session.

@MauryMarkowitz yes naturally that is the case. But every SSMS tab executes in the context of the database shown in the drop down menu.

It appears the error I am having is not due to visibility, but some other issue to do with timing or threading. I will open a new question.
